# How can I see how TypeScript computes types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Problem: I'm working on a file that has a lot of conditional types that derive their types from previously defined conditional types and this has become very complex and difficult to debug how a type is being derived.

I'm trying to find a way to "debug" or list how the TypeScript compiler is making its determination on a conditional type and picking a path to derive the ultimate type.

I've looked through the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) and have not found anything in that area yet...

An analogy to what I'm looking for right now is the equivalent of the `DEBUG=express:*` type of setting that one might use if you wanted to see what an express server was doing.

However, the actual problem I'm trying to solve is to be able to deconstruct and debug how a type is derived in a large complex hierarchical type definition.

Important Note: I'm not trying to debug the runtime execution of TypeScript project. I'm trying to debug how the types are computed by the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: Just use a good IDE, instantiate your type and hover over the value in the source file opened in your editor. Is there some additional desired information you miss by using that suggestion?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - thanks for the reply. When I do that it points to a complex type that has nested conditional types. That in turn points to another similar complex type and it keeps going and sometimes it will branch in a manner that is not obvious. Trying to work out how to debug why that type construction branch is happening.

Comment: I think your question would benefit from a concrete example to demonstrate this. I have also encountered the situation you're describing before, but usually I find the workaround involves rewriting the types such that they're either more opaque (e.g. a generic `interface` with a self-documenting container name instead of a generic `type` that attempts to expand its definition in the IDE's tooltip) or just refactoring the source to avoid overuse of complex conditional types entirely.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts trying to upgrade this repo to Hapi/Joi@16 and debug the type generation is what lead to this question. https://github.com/TCMiranda/joi-extract-type

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this is the specific issue discussing the upgrade itself for context. https://github.com/TCMiranda/joi-extract-type/issues/22

Comment: Try documenting your typing assumptions in tests that exercise the variations you care about. The tests don't necessarily need working code (probably just chains of variable declarations), but the compiler will complain when building them if they're broken. Not only will you catch where your assumptions are violated now, but you'll catch regressions later during future coding as well as typescript version changes.

Comment: Look at generated JavaScript via here perhaps? http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Answer (score 14):

There isn't any built-in mechanism in typescript to log out the desired info in question. However, if you are interested in understanding internal work, here's the place in source code where the actually resolving of conditional types happens.

Take a look at these places in [`checker.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ba5e86f1406f39e89d56d4b32fd6ff8de09a0bf3/src/compiler/checker.ts).

ln:13258 `instantiateTypeWorker()`
ln:12303 `getConditionalType()`
ln:12385 `getTypeFromConditionalTypeNode()`
ln:12772 `getTypeFromTypeNode()`

---

Attached is a half-done typescript plugin I put together carelessly. It logs out the raw data structure of a `ConditionalType`. To understand this struct, check [types.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ba5e86f1406f39e89d56d4b32fd6ff8de09a0bf3/src/compiler/types.ts) ln:4634.

UX of this plugin is terrible, but that struct does tell you how typescript decides the final value of a conditional type.

```js
import stringify from "fast-safe-stringify";

function init(modules: {
  typescript: typeof import("typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary");
}) {
  const ts = modules.typescript;

  // #region utils
  function replacer(name, val) {
    if (name === "checker" || name === "parent") {
      return undefined;
    }
    return val;
  }

  function getContainingObjectLiteralElement(node) {
    var element = getContainingObjectLiteralElementWorker(node);
    return element &&
      (ts.isObjectLiteralExpression(element.parent) ||
        ts.isJsxAttributes(element.parent))
      ? element
      : undefined;
  }

  ts.getContainingObjectLiteralElement = getContainingObjectLiteralElement;
  function getContainingObjectLiteralElementWorker(node) {
    switch (node.kind) {
      case 10 /* StringLiteral */:
      case 14 /* NoSubstitutionTemplateLiteral */:
      case 8 /* NumericLiteral */:
        if (node.parent.kind === 153 /* ComputedPropertyName */) {
          return ts.isObjectLiteralElement(node.parent.parent)
            ? node.parent.parent
            : undefined;
        }
      // falls through
      case 75 /* Identifier */:
        return ts.isObjectLiteralElement(node.parent) &&
          (node.parent.parent.kind === 192 /* ObjectLiteralExpression */ ||
            node.parent.parent.kind === 272) /* JsxAttributes */ &&
          node.parent.name === node
          ? node.parent
          : undefined;
    }
    return undefined;
  }

  function getPropertySymbolsFromContextualType(
    node,
    checker,
    contextualType,
    unionSymbolOk
  ) {
    var name = ts.getNameFromPropertyName(node.name);
    if (!name) return ts.emptyArray;
    if (!contextualType.isUnion()) {
      var symbol = contextualType.getProperty(name);
      return symbol ? [symbol] : ts.emptyArray;
    }
    var discriminatedPropertySymbols = ts.mapDefined(
      contextualType.types,
      function(t) {
        return ts.isObjectLiteralExpression(node.parent) &&
          checker.isTypeInvalidDueToUnionDiscriminant(t, node.parent)
          ? undefined
          : t.getProperty(name);
      }
    );
    if (
      unionSymbolOk &&
      (discriminatedPropertySymbols.length === 0 ||
        discriminatedPropertySymbols.length === contextualType.types.length)
    ) {
      var symbol = contextualType.getProperty(name);
      if (symbol) return [symbol];
    }
    if (discriminatedPropertySymbols.length === 0) {
      // Bad discriminant -- do again without discriminating
      return ts.mapDefined(contextualType.types, function(t) {
        return t.getProperty(name);
      });
    }
    return discriminatedPropertySymbols;
  }
  ts.getPropertySymbolsFromContextualType = getPropertySymbolsFromContextualType;

  function getNodeForQuickInfo(node) {
    if (ts.isNewExpression(node.parent) && node.pos === node.parent.pos) {
      return node.parent.expression;
    }
    return node;
  }
  // #endregion

  /**
   * plugin code starts here
   */
  function create(info: ts.server.PluginCreateInfo) {
    const log = (s: any) => {
      const prefix =
        ">>>>>>>> [TYPESCRIPT-FOOBAR-PLUGIN] <<<<<<<< \n";
      const suffix = "\n<<<<<<<<<<<";
      if (typeof s === "object") {
        s = stringify(s, null, 2);
      }
      info.project.projectService.logger.info(prefix + String(s) + suffix);
    };

    // Diagnostic logging
    log("PLUGIN UP AND RUNNING");

    // Set up decorator
    const proxy: ts.LanguageService = Object.create(null);
    for (let k of Object.keys(info.languageService) as Array<
      keyof ts.LanguageService
    >) {
      const x = info.languageService[k];
      proxy[k] = (...args: Array<{}>) => x.apply(info.languageService, args);
    }

    proxy.getQuickInfoAtPosition = (filename, position) => {
      var program = ts.createProgram(
        [filename],
        info.project.getCompilerOptions()
      );
      var sourceFiles = program.getSourceFiles();
      var sourceFile = sourceFiles[sourceFiles.length - 1];
      var checker = program.getDiagnosticsProducingTypeChecker();
      var node = ts.getTouchingPropertyName(sourceFile, position);
      var nodeForQuickInfo = getNodeForQuickInfo(node);
      var nodeType = checker.getTypeAtLocation(nodeForQuickInfo);

      let res;
      if (nodeType.flags & ts.TypeFlags.Conditional) {
        log(stringify(nodeType, replacer, 2));
      }

      if (!res)
        res = info.languageService.getQuickInfoAtPosition(filename, position);
      return res;
    };

    return proxy;
  }

  return { create };
}

export = init;
```

Some annoyingly detailed instructions to get this plugin running:

1. `mkdir my-ts-plugin && cd my-ts-plugin`
2. `touch package.json` and write `{ "name": "my-ts-plugin", "main": "index.js" }`
3. `yarn add typescript fast-safe-stringify`
4. copy-paste this snippet to `index.ts`, use tsc to compile it to `index.js`
5. `yarn link`
6. now `cd` to your own ts project's dir, run `yarn link my-ts-plugin`
7. add `{ "compilerOptions": { "plugins": [{ "name": "my-ts-plugin" }] } }` to your `tsconfig.json`
8. add to workspace setting`(.vscode/settings.json)` this line: `{ "typescript.tsdk": "<PATH_TO_YOUR_TS_PROJECT>/node_modules/typescript/lib" }`
9. open vscode command palette and run:

   1. `TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version... -> Use Workspace Version`
   2. `TypeScript: Restart TS Server`
   3. `TypeScript: Open TS Server Log`
10. you should be able to see the plugin log out `"PLUGIN UP AND RUNNING"`, now open a ts code file and mouse hover to some conditional type node, you should see a loooooong json data struct added to the log file.

Comment: Thanks for that @hackape. I've been hacking around with it and can produce some logs which are interesting and pretty much list what I'm seeing interactively when using VSCode so it hasn't got me much further than where I was. Good instructions on how to get that plugin working.

Comment: I gave the bounty to you. Even though it hasn't gotten me to the solution I think that with more effort on my part modifying that plugin I could probably get there and I can't image that there's be a better solution to this in the near future. Thanks for your help and effort!

Comment: I'm not going to mark this as the correct answer in case an exact solution is presented by someone in the future.

Comment: @Guy Thanks for the bounty. So I spent a couple more hours yesterday trying to get more useful result. You're right. The data struct above captures the AST-ish object of the conditional type chain, but it's just the parsed result, not the evaluated result. As to the "why" or which conditional branch the type resolver take when evaluating, it requires dumping out results of all intermediate steps, kinda like putting a `debugger` to pause somewhere then manually look through local scopes in the call stacks.

Comment: I modified the `getConditionalType()` in `checker.ts` to make a custom build typescript, inserting some side effect logic to dump out intermediate info along the way. And this time I got something a bit more useful. I'll clean up my code and attach a gist later.

Comment: @Guy the gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/hackape/f6b3d61d26d632ff48ac4c59232b503d)

Answer (score 5):

One trick I'm using to figure out the path taken when using conditional types, is to replace values with string literals.

So say you have:

```
type SomeComplexType<T> = T extends string ? /* Condition A */ : /* Condition B */
```

Where `Condition A` and `Condition B` are two deeply nested paths full of other conditions, I replace it with:

```
type SomeComplexType<T> = T extends string ? "string" : "noString"
```

Then when using it like:

```
type result = SomeComplexType<"myComplexType">
```

You can hover over `result` and it will show the resolved value of `SomeComplexType`, in this case either `"string"` or `"noString"`.
Once you know the resolved value, you can replace it with your original condition and perform the same steps one level deeper.

It's not ideal but it's better than nothing.